# linux - centOS 6.2 block IP starts with

Tags: linux, block

Is it possible to block an IP starting with?

For example i want to block ALL IPs that starting with

188.67.

Is there a command or a way for that?

My problem:

I have a game server, and A person keeps accessing into with with a proxy server, all of his IPs are starting with 188.67.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -s 188.67/16 -j DROP
```

which will drop all packets from IP addresses from 188.67.0.0 to 188.67.255.255. If this works and you're happy with it then use

```
service iptables save
```

to write the new configuration to /etc/sysconfig/iptables.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. But keep in mind that you will be blocking lots of other legitimate users who might visit your server from the 188.67 IP.

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s 188.67.0.0/16 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

You can change the -p option depending on which protocol your server uses, and --dport for the port number on which the server is listening.